Slides stack on page load
I'm facing an issue with slick.js. The snippet I inserted is showing it too, but not as long as it is on my website.
I've checked the loading order for slick and the other JS files. And as far as I know, the order should be correct. The only reason I can see is that the slick files and function are loading slower than the content itself.
Note: CDN is just for the snipped. For my project, I load it locally.
Things I tried:

Loading the slick.js as one of the first files after jQuery
Loading it with async
Loading the slick.js and its function before the content (which didn't work at all)
Suggestion from herrstrietzel (did not make any difference)

What can I do to avoid this loading issue?



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide-container').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i></button>',
    refresh: true
  });
});
.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
}

.customer-slide {
  background: #000;
  height: 96vh !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.slider-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-text h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.slick-dots li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #cecece20;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background: #000;
}
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slide-container mobile">
    <div class="customer-slide">
      <div class="slider-text">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-slide">
      <div class="slider-text">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>



EDIT
Something I tried too. I thought adding a time-out and an if statement with a specific slick class this would also help but... No.


$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$('.slide-container').hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
      $('.slide-container').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i></button>'
      });
    }
  }, 600);
});



Here is an image of the problem


Maybe try to load slick locally (js and css) see if it helps

Ah, sorry, forgot to mention that I already load it locally for my website. Just did it via CDN for this snipped

The snippet works fine. As you're loading slick.js in the footer of your HTML the loading order is as expected. Please clarify what's the actual problem. If  you're aiming at a faster execution of slick you may move the slick.js to the header and add the defer attribute.

@herrstrietzel I've tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work. And yes, I was/am  aiming for a faster execution.

This is the best solution I've come up with so far. By adding an extra class and a timeout function to this class. This delays the load of the second slide and prevents the overlapping/stacking.


setTimeout(function() {
  $('.hide-slide').removeClass('hide-slide');
}, 100);
.hide-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}



